# Looking for a way to build a Flutter app to view and search through PDF files

Tags: flutter, pdf, mobile-application

I want to build a Flutter mobile app that can be used to view some PDFs. I am looking for a package/solution for it.

It should

1. render PDF files
2. enable users to search for text and highlight all instances within the PDF view (like it happens in most PDF viewers).
3. Additionally, implement arrow buttons for seamless navigation between matching cases (like it happens in most PDF viewers)

I cannot simply open the file in another viewer because the app is supposed to be limited. The PDF files should not be shared or printed for e.g. It needs to be a controlled viewer.

Challenge:

1. Limited Package Options:
   Existing Flutter packages are inadequate for our requirements. The sole available package we found, Syncfusion PDF view, suffers from slow page loading times.
2. Text Search Limitations:
   Other packages convert PDFs to images, rendering text unsearchable, thus hindering the desired functionality.
3. Offline Function:
   We need this to work offline directly with the file for areas with bad network.

Comment: You might want to include all packages that you've tried and mention what they're lacking of